# how can I cache an image in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, nscache

I am having trouble finding a good example of how I can cache images in a table view using `URLSession` to get image from the internet (API).

However, I am getting issues with the cache - Here is my code so far:

```swift
func configure(with urlString: String, name: String, address: String, station: String) {
    
    var imageCache = NSCache<UIImage, String>()
    
    loader.startAnimating()
    loader.isHidden = false
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, _, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        let locationImage = UIImage(data: data)
        
        imageCache.setObject(locationImage!, forKey: urlString)
        
        imageCache[url] = locationImage
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.nameLabel.text = name
            self?.addressLabel.text = address
            self?.locationImageView.image = locationImage
            self?.loader.stopAnimating()
            self?.loader.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

[image: screnshot of code]

errors include:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UIImage'
> Value of type 'NSCache<UIImage, AnyObject>' has no subscripts
> 'NSCache' requires that 'String' be a class type

Comment: Also, if the `configure` method is part of the table view cell class, then you're not instantiating the cache at the proper place. And you should also take care regarding the http request, as you don't want to end up in situations where a reused cell gets populated with contents from an incorrect cell.

Comment: yes this is the issue i was getting also - i have contents in incorrect cells - how can i address this? where should instantiate the cache ?

Comment: i moved this outside the configure method is this okay or should i do this directly in the cell  (cellforrow) at method @cristik ?

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```swift
var imageCache = NSCache<UIImage, String>()
```

creates a cache where the key type is `UIImage` and the objects stored in the cache are `String`s. You want it to be the other way round with one caveat: NSCache doesn't support `String` for the key type, it has to be `NSString`:

```swift
var imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
```

That way you'll be able to put `UIImage`s into the cache while identifying them by URL strings.

Check out my demo project on GitHub: https://github.com/vadimbelyaev/ImagesCache

Comment: I managed to find a nice and easy solution to caching images - kingfisher install on cocopods

Comment: Yes, there are many libraries that would do image loading and caching: Kingfisher, SDWebImage, Nuke to name a few. But sometimes you just need a simple solution that you can implement in one short class that uses NSCache instead of adding a fairly complex 3rd party dependency to the project.